# CSS - Prevent background image from moving when zooming out

Tags: html, css

Below is my code for my situation.

Currently the background image just gets smaller as I scroll out. I don't want it to repeat; I just want it to stay in place as I scroll out.

```
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: url("/img/background.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need `background-size:cover` in the body

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code

Use this in Body

```
background-size: cover;
```

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: url("/img/background.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Add some comments or a description to explain the solution for other people who find this answer.